# Adding unit attributes to an xarray object

Tags: python-xarray, metpy

I have created an array of isobaric pressure levels to plot a cross section:

```
vertical, = cross['isobaric'].metpy.coordinates('vertical')
```

however, this array has values in units of Pa. To convert into hPa, I created a new array:

```
vert_hpa = (vertical/100)*units.hPa
```

I then want to use this to calculate potential temperature:

```
temperature, pressure, relative_humidity = xr.broadcast(cross['temperature'], vert_hpa, cross['relative_humidity'])
theta = mpcalc.potential_temperature(pressure, temperature)
```

When I attempt to run this, I get an error which suggests that the array I've created and assigned to the variable 'pressure' doesn't have any associated units:

```
ValueError: `potential_temperature` given arguments with incorrect units: `pressure` requires "[pressure]" but given "dimensionless".
```

The [MetPy units documentation](https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/units.html) suggests that units can be added to an array using the syntax array_name*units.unit. Why has my attempt to do this been unsuccessful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're running into is that multiplying units works with numpy arrays, but not with `xarray.DataArray` instances--which is what you get when you get `vertical`. It'd be nice if this weren't so, but currently that's the world we live in. To get around this MetPy has some helpful tools for [xarray and units](https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/tutorials/xarray_tutorial.html#units).

In this case, though, there's no need to manually convert your units from Pa to hPa--the beauty of the unit support is as long as the units are known and of the proper dimensionality, `potential_temperature` does not care what they are. This is how I would write your code:

```
vertical = data['temperature'].metpy.vertical
temperature, pressure, relative_humidity = xr.broadcast(data['temperature'],
                                                        vertical,
                                                        data['relative_humidity'])
theta = mpcalc.potential_temperature(pressure, temperature)
```

For future reference, if you do need to take an xarray and convert it to just a bare numpy array with units attached, you can use the `unit_array` attribute:

```
temp_with_units = temperature.metpy.unit_array
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It makes sense that this conversion is not needed to convert from Pa to hPa here, but later in the script I want to plot a cross-section and when the pressure array ('vertical') is in units of Pa, I end up with a plot that's 95% white space with RH data at the very bottom. Is my best option to convert xarray->numpy array->add units->back to xarray?

Comment: You want the `convert_units` method which is shown in the xarray tutorial I linked to in my answer.